# Downloaded file is empty or fails to find it to begin download

Tags: php, html, download

I'm trying to download some files from a site but keep encountering problems.  Firstly it was downloading an empty file, I thought that was because of content type, someone on SO suggested application/octet-stream which I am now doing.  I then had a lot of issues with it actually finding the file.  After a few test cases it was the whitespace issue, I then amend that (put in "") and I now download an empty file again.

Rudimentary code but hoping someone can help:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$dir = "training/trainingDocuments/";
$downloadFilename = $dir.$filename;
//ftp://site.com///training/trainingDocuments/8%20-%20SUBSEA%20QUESTIONS__51f034ab37a8e.xls
//$downloadFilename = preg_replace('/\s/', '%', $downloadFilename);

//8 - SUBSEA QUESTIONS__51f034ab37a8e.xls
//if the filename exists
if(is_file($downloadFilename)){

//send the headers
header('Pragma: public'); //FIX IE6 Content-Disposition
header('Content-DEscription: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transder-Encoding: binary');
header(sprintf('Content-Length: %u', filesize($downloadFilename)));
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$downloadFilename."");

}else{
//file doesn't exist
echo "File no exist\n\n";
echo $downloadFilename;
}//end if file exists
```

Comment: You actually, you need to do what JohnnyFaldo AND Marc B said :)

Comment: Don't understand why it was voted down, valid question, or so I though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never actually OUTPUT the file, e.g. you're missing

```
readfile($downloadFilename);
```

as well, note that your code allows a malicious user to download **ANY** file on your server that they know the path for. Consider

```
$_GET['file'] = '../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd';
```

Comment: Amazing! thanks!  Can you suggest a better way of doing it for added protection?

Comment: Try [basename()](http://php.net/basename) to strip off any possible pathing information.

Comment: Hold on...The get['filename'] only gets the actual name of the file, it's already been stripped of path etc.  When it gets passed to the donwload page I then append the path to it.  Does this not do the same as baseline?

Comment: consider someone manually hitting the url `http://example.com/yourscript.php?filename=../../../../../etc/passwd`. Just because you might have some client-side filename stripping stuff, doesn't mean someone can't FORGE a request to your site with the malicious path in it. Unless you're processing/modifying $_GET on the server, which is another thing...

Answer (score 1):

typo here:

```
header('Content-Transder-Encoding: binary');
```

should be:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

try that

Comment: :) - no still empty file

Comment: have you checked the value of $_GET['filename'] ?

Comment: johnny, all values are correct, if was missing the readfile as the other answer suggested

Comment: Cheers for the help!  I'm getting close to my 6 question quota.  Any idea how I can display it in a new window?  Like when you click a pdf and it opens up in new window.  That'd be a nice option, Goooooogle!!

Comment: @user2608855 `<a href="link_to_file.xxx" target="_blank">LINK NAME</a>`. You may need to escape `"` or use single quotes.

Comment: @Fred thanks! I was literally just typing that as a test whenthe message came through.  missed the target=blank though which i expect is important :)

Comment: @user2608855 You're welcome. Google `href target` and you will see other ways to open a link, such as `same`, `parent`, etc. Cheers.

Comment: I will do.  Having fun with escaping the var at the mo -.-